# Symfony Doctrine optimisation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have MN relation between USER and CATEGORY table. Problem appear when user has more than 100 interests. When I execute very simple query like this:

```
  return $this->createQueryBuilder('usercategory')
        ->innerJoin('usercategory.user', 'u')
        ->innerJoin('usercategory.category', 'c')
        ->where('u.id = :user_id')
        ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Symfony profiler reported that more than 100 queries are executed with more than 150ms time for execution. 90% of those queries look like

```
SELECT t0.category_name AS category_name1,t0.type AS type2, t0.status AS status3,  t0.category_id AS category_id4, t0.parent_id AS parent_id5 FROM categories t0 WHERE t0.category_id = ?
```

This mean, if user has 100 categories, doctrine will execute 100 query to fetch them all.

Am i doing something wrong and how i can use make it faster by using DQL?

thx,
MIlos

Comment: ->addSelect('c') will cause the categories to be returned from your query (as opposed to lazy loading them).

Comment: @Cerad Please make your comment as answer so i can accept it. thx again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
->addSelect('c')
```

will cause the categories to be returned from your query (as opposed to lazy loading them).